# C++ 11 get pointer of a std::function

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to store and identify `std::function` objects in a `std::map`.
To identify I want to use the `std::function::target`.
I can't get the pointer from `std::function::target` if I use `std::bind` to bind to a member function from a class.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;
void normal_fun(int a)
{
    std::cout << "hello\n"<<a;
}

class testclass
{
public:
    int b;
    void mytest(int a)
    {
        b = a;
    }
};

uintptr_t getFuncAddress(std::function<void(int)> &f)
{
    uintptr_t returnAddress = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(f.target<void(*)(int)>());
    return returnAddress;
}

int main()
{

    testclass c;
    std::function<void(int)> f1 = bind(&testclass::mytest,&c, placeholders::_1);
    std::function<void(int)> f2 = normal_fun;
    auto addrF1 = getFuncAddress(f1);
    auto addrF2 = getFuncAddress(f2);
}
```

How can I achieve what I want to do?

Comment: You don't store an actual `void(int)` in `std::function`, so `target` return a `nullptr` as it's supposed to. You store the result of bind, which is some unknown functor type.

Comment: That is what i fear... Do you know how can i write the `target` to get the pointer from an bind???

Comment: If you need to do that, I think you are reaching for the wrong tool. `std::function` is about type erasure. Trying to get the exact target by type is sort of like littering your code with `dynamic_cast`s instead of relying on polymorphism.

Comment: Why not use the `iterator` of the `map` to identify the function?

Comment: @Pixelchemist how do you get the `std::function` into the map if it's not sortable?

Comment: @Pixelchemist that is the origin Problem. std::function don't give a hash and without a hash i can't sort or identify the function. And my idea is that i use the pointer of the function which is behind the std::function because the Docu say that std::function is only a wrapper....

Comment: @JonathanWakely there is no such requirement as long as `std::function` is a value, not a key. The opposite not explicitly stated in the question.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: You don't unless it is not only the value but also the key. It sounds like an **xy** problem. If you don't have a property / `key` (which is different from your `T`) yet, for which sorting is sensible [why would you want *sorting* if thats just a way to identify your stored objects?] , `std::map` is probably the wrong tool in the first place. If you'd want to store objects of the same type in a sorted manner, you'd go for `set` but I'd probably just store it in a `list` and use the `list::iterator` to access it.

Comment: @bdahl: Why do you want to **sort** your `std::function` objects? If this is just a mechanism to identify them, you could use something like a `list<function<...>>` and use the `iterators` to identify every function.[Where you'd (admittedly) have to keep track of the iterators (i.e. when passing the `list` around). I understand that a `map` key doesn't have this downside.]

Comment: @Pixelchemist The Problem by the list is that i want only store a unique instance of every functional object. For this i need an entity to compare if this entity is registered yet.

Comment: @bdahl: The problem will be that even though there might be an option to distinguish real function pointers by address, a call to `bind` is quite likely to return distinct wrappers for every call to `bind` - even if you use the same arguments. So as I guess the problem isn't really "How to use `function::target` as a Key for `map`?" but rather more like "How do I prevent duplicates (instances of the same functional object) in a collection of `std::function` objects?".

Comment: @Pixelchemist, _"you could use something like a `list<function<...>>` and use the iterators to identify every function"_ Right, my point was that iterators into a _map_ isn't very helpful. The `std::function` can't be the key in a map, and if it's the value you don't need to use iterators into it, you can use the key. But using an unsorted sequence with stable iterators (like a `list`) makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to store and identify std::function objects in a std::map.

I assume, you want to identify `std::function` objects (e.g. to call or delete them selectively).
In such situations, I use an additional key e.g. a simple `unsigned`.
A global function may be used:

```
typedef unsigned Key;

Key genId()
{
  static Key id = 0;
  return ++id;
}
```

Now, the `std::function` objects can be paired with this key. The API may grant that access to paired `std::function` objects can be done using the key exclusively.

Comment: The problem with this is that two `std::function` objects that contain the same target will have different keys, which might not meet the OP's needs.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Yep, I expected this answer. We use a signal-slot concept inspired by sigc++. We try to prevent such situations by "well balanced" accesses and by tracking connections. Finally, two identical targets are permitted and might be (in rare cases) a feature instead of a bug.

Comment: About this thread i think it's the best way to put a random Key in the Classes which contains my memberfunctions.

Comment: @bdahl The ultimate random key for this task could be a UUID.

Answer (score 2):

A `std::function` is not a function pointer.  It is not even a pointer.

If you know what type is stored in a `std::function`, you can get a pointer to what it stores.  Note that the pointer here is not the function pointer, but a pointer to the function pointer.

If you do not know what type it stores, you cannot.

If you want `<` or `==` or `hash` (etc), `std::function` does not provide this for you.  It type erases `()`, copy, move, destruction, typeid, and cast-back-to-original.

You can use type erasure techniques to augment a `std::function` with those operations; note that type erasure on binary operations is a touch trickier than type erasure is in general.

Type erasing something shouldn't be your first go-to when solving a problem, but it will solve your problem.  There are articles on type erasure in SO documentation for C++.  This isn't a beginner subject.

Odds are your underlying problem can be solved in a much simpler way.

In any case, using the type returned from `target` to order is not a great idea, as it is a pointer to a possibly automatic storage object, or possibly heap storage object; the two of which are going to have significantly different invalidation rules under innocuous operations (like move).  A SBO (small buffer optimization) target is going to move with the instance of the `std::function`, while a heap-allocated one is likely to stay with the state the `std::function` moves around under `std::move`-like operations.  This is a real mess.

Answer (score 2):

The point of `std::function` is to give a uniform interface and type for callable objects that meet a given signature. You are expecting it to also provide a uniform key for sorting, but it doesn't do that. There is no way to sort function pointers and arbitrary function objects and callables returned by `std::bind`. They are completely different things, and comparing them doesn't make sense. All `std::function` allows you to do is store them and call them.

If you need a sorting mechanism you'll have to invent something yourself, you won't get it from `std::function`.

Comment: "*If you need a sorting mechanism you'll have to invent something yourself, you won't get it from `std::function`.*" That's like putting the cart before the horse. If you need to "invent" some mechanism to sort your objects you probably don't need them to be sorted in the first place. On the other hand, if you need them to be sorted, you already should know the sorting condition from the problem you're trying to solve and you can use this information to come up with a hashing or sorting mechanism.

Comment: @Pixelchemist yes great point. I think the key is whether you "need" it or not, and as you say, if you can't describe a meaningful key to sort you probably don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

```
f.target<void(*)(int)>
```

Is wrong, because the type returned by bind is not `void(*)(int)`, so the target will never return a non-null pointer. Bind does not return a function pointer. It returns some object of implementation specified type.

The type can be acquired with `decltype`. This is a bit perverse, but should be correct:

```
f.target<decltype(bind(
  &testclass::mytest,
  (testclass*)nullptr,
  placeholders::_1)
)>
```

> but i have the Problem that i didn't know in getFuncAddress if i have testclass or myOtherClass or someone else Class

You can only use `std::function::target` if you know the type of the wrapped object. If the number of choices is limited, then you can try to get the target with each type until non-null is returned. For an arbitrary unknown type, `std::function::target` can not be of any use for you.

---

> I want to store and identify std::function objects in a std::map

I think you will have to use some external key, that cannot be extracted from the `std::function`. This means that if you wish to prevent duplicates, you also need an external method of guaranteeing a unique mapping from key to the function.

Comment: Ok yes that is ok but i have the Problem that i didn't know in `getFuncAddress` if i have `testclass` or `myOtherClass` or someone else Class. I know only the signature of the memberfunction is `void(int)`...